# Hide Parent Element from Screen Reader Accessibility without Hiding its Children Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

I want to hide Parent Element from the Screen Readers (Talkback) Accessibility but want Children Elements to be Screen Readers (Talkback) Accessible.

This is the HTML code being used

```
 <div tabIndex=-1> 
     Parent Element
     <div>Child 1</div>
     <div tabIndex=-1>
         Child 2
         <div>Child 3</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <button>Tab Button</button>
```

Code can be executed at https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=694eb65e573f

NOTE - Tab Index Property with -1 value is used to make the element Keyboard Focusable and I need it for my project.

As per my understanding,

| Property | Property Value | Accessible via Tab | Keyboard Focusable | Accessible via Screen Readers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | None | NO | NO | NO |
| tabIndex | -1 | NO | YES | YES |
| tabIndex | 0 | YES | YES | YES |

What I want to achieve for Parent Element is
**TAB Accessibility : NO, KEYBOARD FOCUS: YES, SCREEN READER ACCESSIBILITY: NO**, without changing accessibility for Children Element.

*I tried tabIndex -1 with aria-hidden = TRUE, I was able to achieve the desired result but aria-hidden removed the Children Element from accessibility via Screen Readers as well.*

Comment: A point of clarity: `tabindex=-1` does *not* make an element keyboard focusable. It makes the element *programmatically* focusable using the `.focus()` method. This is typically used in 'single page' sites and web apps to focus the new main heading after a client side reroute. If an element is going to receive input (e.g. from the keyboard) it's *operable*, and should be a proper tab stop (`tabindex=0`) or a focused-managed child/descendent of a proper tab stop. Maybe you could explain why you need something focusable to be hidden from screen readers? When and how does it get focus?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I want to use Parent Element as a wrapper and handle incoming focus requests there and do not want Screen Reader to access the wrapper, only the main child element.

Comment: OK, what you're describing seems to be a case where you need to manage keyboard focus within a *widget* role. Widget (parent) gets focus using tab, then arrow keys manipulate the focus within, using one of two equally reliable techniques, either "Roving Tabindex" or `aria-activedescendant` These are described in some detail at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#kbd_general_within

Comment: Please note-- [Rule #4 of ARIA is "Don't hide focusable elements from the accessibility tree"](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#fourth).